# How to write RenderViewToString in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, viewengine

I m using this method for render view in ASP.NET core. But it returns empty. What is the reason? Please help me.
I tried different ways like this link https://www.learnrazorpages.com/advanced/render-partial-to-string it didnt work

```
    protected string RenderViewAsync(string viewName, object model)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
        {
            viewName = ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
        }

        ViewData.Model = model;

        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            IViewEngine viewEngine = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ICompositeViewEngine)) as ICompositeViewEngine;
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = viewEngine.FindView(ControllerContext, viewName, false);

            if (viewResult.Success == false)
            {
                return $"A view with the name {viewName} could not be found";
            }

            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(
                ControllerContext,
                viewResult.View,
                ViewData,
                TempData,
                writer,
                new HtmlHelperOptions()
            );

            viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);

            return writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference between my article which you linked to, and your code is that in my example, the `RenderViewAsync` equivalent method is `async` and returns a `Task<string>`, and the call to `RenderAsync` is awaited. If you don't await an asynchronous method call, the program continues to operate as if nothing has happened. You never get the result of the operation.

Try changing the method signature to make it `async` and return a `Task<string>`:

```
protected async Task<string> RenderViewAsync(string viewName, object model)
```

Then await the `RenderAsync` method call in the last but one line:

```
await viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);
```